# Cozyroc SSIS : Unable to use SFTP task

Tags: ssis, customtool

I am trying to use cozyroc tool sftpTask, first all the component were not present in the toolbox so I changed project setting from **SQL server 2016** to **SQL server 2014**, after that all the tools came up to the toolbox.
[Image of Project Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5SzB.png)

Now when I use SFTP task and click on the **Action** property in the edit mode, I get error message show in the next image [Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rlDT.png)

so please help me fix the issue

I am using

Visual Studio 2015

SQL Server data tools 2015

Microsoft sql server 2014 management studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the problem is : [Here is the link to the solution](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/microsoft/msdn-disc-2729/microsoft-datawarehouse-vsintegration-dll/)
**Manually Register Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.DLL Using Microsoft Register Server**

When you install software that uses the Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.DLL dependency, the software should automatically register the file for you. In some cases your DLL file may not register properly, and as a result, will provide a "Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.DLL not registered" error. Fortunately, you can use a built-in utility called "Microsoft Register Server" (regsvr32.exe) to re-register your Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.DLL file.

How to re-register Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.DLL from an elevated command prompt (Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, and 10):

1.Click the Start button.
2.Type "command" in the search box... DO NOT hit ENTER yet!
3.While holding CTRL-Shift on your keyboard, hit ENTER.
4.You will be prompted with a permission dialog box.
5.Click Yes.
6.Type the following command: regsvr32 /u Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.DLL.
7.Hit ENTER. This will UN-REGISTER your file.
8.Type the following command: regsvr32 /i Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.DLL.
9.Hit ENTER. This will RE-REGISTER your file.
10.Close the command prompt window.
11.Re-start the program associated with Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.DLL error.